# SQLite UPDATE multiple rows with a single value based on variable text

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

First off, apologies if this has been covered in a previous post and I've missed it. I've done a lot of searching and haven't come across anything that has worked so far.

I'm currently using the below query to update records in a table.

```
UPDATE table SET Column1="1" WHERE Column2 LIKE "Text";
```

The problem is I have over 100,000 rows, each with different text, to update and even doing 15,000 at a time takes 45 mins. I'm new to SQL, but I'm fairly certain that isn't the most efficient way to update the rows I need to update.

I've been trying to use other suggestions I've come across on here but none have worked so far.

Comment: What exactly is the expected behavior of the query?  What are the other suggestions that you have tried?

Comment: There is no variable in that query. Do you mean that `"Text"` is different for different rows?

Comment: Do you have any indexes? Why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=`?

Comment: I should have said varying text, as opposed to Variable, sorry. Yes the "Text is different for each row.

Comment: I was using LIKE from another query I had which was to update another field based on another value, where LIKE was appropriate.

The query in its context is
UPDATE Aircraft SET Interested="1" WHERE Registration LIKE "ZK-OKN";
and so on for different Registrations.

Comment: I have tried others like 
`UPDATE mytable
    SET myfield = CASE other_field
        WHEN 1 THEN 'value'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'value'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'value'`
which hasn't worked. 

Part of the problem I have is, I suspect, that not all of the Registrations I am trying to update will be in the Database, so I need the query to be able to skip them if it cannot find them.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to look up records fast, you need indexes on the relevant columns.
(See [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) for details.)

In this particular case, you need an index on `Column2`.
`LIKE` is case-insensitive, so you must create a case-insensitive index, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX MyTable_Column2 ON MyTable(Column2 COLLATE NOCASE);
```

Furthermore, `Column2` must have been declared with `TEXT` [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

---

Wrap multiple updates into one transaction, otherwise the transaction overhead will be much larger than the time needed for the actual updates.

---

You can always check with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) whether your query is able to use an index.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go. As for the update query, should I keep that the same or is there an improved way of doing that?

Comment: If you try to update multiple records with one statement, it's more likely that SQLite will do a full table scan.